# Strange out of scope variable

Tags: c, variables, scope, arguments

I was looking up the [`getopt`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html#Getopt) command and I discovered that using the function seems to inexplicably produce another variable called `optarg`. You can see an example of this [in the following program I swiped from Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getopt#Example_1_.28using_getopt.29)

```
#include <stdio.h>     /* for printf */
#include <stdlib.h>    /* for exit */
#include <unistd.h>    /* for getopt */
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    int c;
    int digit_optind = 0;
    int aopt = 0, bopt = 0;
    char *copt = 0, *dopt = 0;
    while ( (c = getopt(argc, argv, "abc:d:012")) != -1) {
        int this_option_optind = optind ? optind : 1;
        switch (c) {
        case '0':
        case '1':
        case '2':
            if (digit_optind != 0 && digit_optind != this_option_optind)
              printf ("digits occur in two different argv-elements.\n");
            digit_optind = this_option_optind;
            printf ("option %c\n", c);
            break;
        case 'a':
            printf ("option a\n");
            aopt = 1;
            break;
        case 'b':
            printf ("option b\n");
            bopt = 1;
            break;
        case 'c':
            printf ("option c with value '%s'\n", optarg);
            copt = optarg;
            break;
        case 'd':
            printf ("option d with value '%s'\n", optarg);
            dopt = optarg;
            break;
        case '?':
            break;
        default:
            printf ("?? getopt returned character code 0%o ??\n", c);
        }
    }
    if (optind < argc) {
        printf ("non-option ARGV-elements: ");
        while (optind < argc)
            printf ("%s ", argv[optind++]);
        printf ("\n");
    }
    exit (0);
}
```

Notice that `optarg` is now being used seemingly without be declared or initialized. Maybe this is just a common feature in C that I am unaware of, but I have been googling for a few hours and I don't know the name of what I am looking for. Any explanations would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the man page

```
GETOPT(3)                BSD Library Functions Manual                GETOPT(3)

NAME
     getopt -- get option character from command line argument list

LIBRARY  
     Standard C Library (libc, -lc)  

SYNOPSIS  
     #include <unistd.h>  

     extern char *optarg;  
     extern int optind;  
     extern int optopt;  
     extern int opterr;  
     extern int optreset;  

     int  
     getopt(int argc, char * const argv[], const char *optstring);
```

These variables are declared in the `unistd.h` header file.

Comment: Thank you. I knew what global variables were, but I didn't realize that optarg was declared in unistd.h

Comment: @IrresponsibleNewb Websearch is a very easy way to answer a question like this: http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=optarg

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Or reading the man pages (assuming you're on a unix-alike system, of course). That's why I like to answer this way. In this case bash also provides a `optarg` so you will need to specify the section of the manual to read: `$ man 3 optarg`.

Answer (score 4):

The term is "global variable". If you declare a variable outside of a function, it's accessible inside functions:

```
int i = 7;

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", i); // prints 7
    return 0;
}
```

In the case of `optarg`, the `unistd.h` header declares it as a global `char *` variable with external linkage:

```
extern char *optarg;
```

(see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/getopt.html).

Comment: "Externally stored", like, on a USB stick?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Heh, O.K., I've changed it to "externally-defined" now. Thanks for the comment. Though I kind of like the USB-stick idea. :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB externally defined as in not in a compilation unit your building but one that you're going to link to later.

Comment: I think the term is "external linkage" :-) (as in, "the header declares a global variable with external linkage").

Comment: @KerrekSB: That is *perfect*, thanks! Re-edited now, hopefully for the last time. :-)

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, if you find names but don't know where they are defined or declared, only run the C pre-processor, which is responsible for `#include`, and then search for the term using `grep` or just `more`.

For example

```
gcc -E foo.c >foo.i
```

would put the result of the C pre-processor into foo.i

You could then have a look at the file using more (using / to search)

The file will have references to the include file which includes the definition or declartion.

For example,

 
`more foo.i` 

then 

`/optarg` 

shows the line

 
`extern char *optarg;`

by scrolling upwards (or reverse search `?#` ) I could find 

`# 414 "/usr/include/unistd.h" 3 4`

Answer (score 0):

`optarg` is declared in `<unistd.h>`.

Comment: Surely not - that would violate ODR, non?

Comment: @KerrekSB I'm sure he means its declared in unistd.h using extern, but defined elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

— Variable: char * optarg

This variable is set by getopt to point at the value of the option argument, for those options that accept arguments.

I find this at the [Using Getopt](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Using-Getopt.html#Using-Getopt) websit